# Self user register and email validation without lock account

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to configure the following scenario where the user must receive an email after self registration to validate its account but not been locked during that time.

There are lots of parameters in `identity-mngt.properties` that should match my needs but i cannot get it work.

If `Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=false` i don't receive any email and if `Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=true` i receive the email but i cannot get logged until i confirm the link.

I thought using 
`Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Lock=false` would make it not check account locked when login but it seems not.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Isura has mentioned, if you just want to send out an email to users, when they are added to the system, you can write your own [custom listener](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/User+Store+Listeners) too. For this you need to implement a [UserOperationEventListener](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/listener/UserOperationEventListener.java), and configure it in `<EventListeners>` section of `identity.xml`.

Comment: You can refer [1] and [2] to know more about the UserOperationEventListeners.  

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/user-operation-event-listener-in-wso2.html

[2] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/writing-user-operation-event-listener.html

Answer (score 0):

`Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Lock=true` means the user will be locked when user registration. It is false means, the user will not be locked while registering.

When we click on the email and confirm user means, unlock the locked user. If `Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Lock=false` means, the user is not locked. So, there is no any reason to confirm that user. He is not locked. So, Identity Server will not send any emails.

Thanks
Isura.

Comment: I would have loved to an email confirmation sent by wso2is without the need to lock the user...

Comment: Do you mean just a confirmation email without an activation link ? Because, if we do not lock user, their is no point of activating.

Comment: Yes, but to confirm the email, I need an activation link, or an email validation link if you care about the name. For now I used the account lock option and send an update claim to unlock the user right after.